# Disabling TLSv1 on Apache hosted on Cent OS 6 64 bit

Tags: apache, ssl, centos6

I have a VPS that runs Cent OS 6 that runs an Apache web server. I have SSL's installed on all the doamins but I just did a SSL test on https://www.whynopadlock.com/ and it came back all good other than saying that I needed to diable TLSv1 due to the fact of  PCI requirements state that TLSv1 must be disabled by June 30, 2018 if you run a eCommerce site (which I do on one domain). I dont know what TLSv1 is and Im presuming that TLSv1 is just a standard that can be disabled either in Cent OS or Apache.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol)

For example, to keep only TLS 1.1 & 1.2 support, which is probably what you want to do, use this directive in the httpd-ssl.conf (or at the place you declare the SSL virtual host)  :

> SSLProtocol TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2